# Problems with connect rabbitmq [Laravel][RabbitMQ][Docker]

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq

I'm trying to connect my application (in Laravel) with rabbitMQ, but when trying, this error happens:
[PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPIOException
Error Connecting to server(99): Cannot assign requested address]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmLPo.png

Here's my docker-compose

```
services:
  
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.13
    container_name: nginx
    volumes:
      - "./projects/publisher:/var/www/publisher"
      - "./projects/consumer:/var/www/consumer"
      - "./volumes/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf"
    ports: 
      - "8080:80"
      - "8081:81"
    depends_on:
       - php
       
  php:
    build:
      context: ./volumes/php
    container_name: php
    volumes:
      - "./projects/publisher:/var/www/publisher"
      - "./projects/consumer:/var/www/consumer"
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASS=123.456

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.20
    container_name: mysql
    volumes:
      - "db_data:/var/lib/mysql"
      - "./volumes/mysql/initial-data:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123.456

  rabbitmq:
    build:
      context: ./volumes/rabbitmq
    ports:
      - "15672:15672"
      - "5672:5672"
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-data:/var/lib/rabbitmq

volumes:
  db_data:
```

ps.: Use laradock is not an option. I have to create this docker...
Can you help, me? =)

Answer (score 0):

Put them in the same network and show me the config file of nginx.

example of network in docker compose:

```
 nginx_docker:
    networks:
       - my-network
 rabbit_docker:
    networks:
       my-network:
          aliases:
             - rabbit-net
 app_docker:
    networks:
       my-network:
          aliases:
             - app-net
networks:
  - my-network:
```

use this config for nginx config:

```
server{
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://example.com:port/
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host
    }
    location /myUri {
        proxy_pass http://example.com:port/
        proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host
    }
}
```